# Kentico - different DOCTYPE on different pages

Tags: kentico

I've just realized that some of my pages have a long DOCTYPE, but most pages have the short DOCTYPE like below. I never add this details myself and in all my Master Pages, I don't see/add the DOCTYPE details. My question is how the DOCTYPE got added and how to make all pages use the same short DOCTYPE. I believe the long DOCTYPE may be the cause to mess up some of my navigation for mobile. Thanks for your input!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOCTYPE is set in the main portal template when using the PortalEngine in Kentico with the code `<%=DocType%>`.  This value comes from the **Master page** tab inside the **Pages** application.  You can see an example of this on the [Creating the master page](https://docs.kentico.com/k10tutorial/creating-the-master-page) tutorial in the Kentico documentation.

It's the first field on the tab that you can edit, so you should just be able to set the value to `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

As far as I am aware, each page that has a master page can specify its own document type, so check out each of your master pages.  I think if you check out the link about, this will help you out.

It's also worth checking that no-one has edited the file `CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx` (this is the base for PortalEngine pages).  For reference, the beginning of the file normally looks as follows (in Kentico 10):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CMSPages_PortalTemplate"
    ValidateRequest="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" EnableEventValidation="false"
     Codebehind="PortalTemplate.aspx.cs" %>

<%=DocType%>
<html <%=XHtmlNameSpace%> <%=XmlNamespace%>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Matt has said, if your not using Portal method then the changes could be in several different aspx files in the CMSTemplates directory. These templates would have that namespace defined in them if they were a master page template.

Answer (score -1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

add above doctype in very first line of your master page.

refer below link.

https://docs.kentico.com/k9tutorial/creating-the-master-page

hopes it will help